# Jquery UI slider together with Jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-slider

I would like to put Jquery UI slider into Jquery UI dialog box, when I'm trying to do that Slider is visible but not work inside of dialog box. If I put that slider to the outside of the dialog box it's work perfectly. Can somebody give me the idea how to manage this?

Comment: Can you post some code (html+js) or create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample does work for me

http://jsfiddle.net/YGQaJ/

Comment: Does it work in IE8? I found that the slider does not move in IE8 inside JQuery dialog box